# Windows Unattended: Hide the "Windows Updates are Disabled For This Computer" Message?

Tags: windows-update, unattended, automatic-updates

In `autounattend.xml` I can set `<ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>` to disable automatic updates. However, after installing, Windows still complains loudly that **updates are disabled**.

By manually checking disable updates the message does go away. But how do I do this without requiring user interaction?

Comment: Just curious here. Why the need to turn off automatic updates? Why bother? Is bandwidth?

Comment: @motobói Bandwidth is not an issue and the disable is temporary. But I don't want users seeing this message, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such way in autounattend.xml. Use GPO to disable the **Action Center** (which displays those messages):

```
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar
Item: Remove the Action Center icon
```